# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. found in <Left> <Root>

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and VueJs 2, and during development I found this error, tried to see several solutions on the internet and some here in stackoverflow, but the bug prevails.

#### My first file

`app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'

import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

let wall = require('./components/wall.vue');

let cabecalho = require('./components/cabecalho.vue');

let left = require('./components/menu.vue');

let right = require('./components/right.vue');

let duvida = require('./components/form-duvida.vue');

let content = require('./components/content.vue');



const app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    router,

    components:{cabecalho, wall, left, right, duvida}

}).$mount('#app')
```

#### My second file

`app.blade.php`

```
<div class="main-content" id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

#### Calling vue component in

`main.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <left></left>
@endsection
```

Comment: You are importing vue twice `window.Vue = require('vue'); import Vue from vue'`. And why are you assigning Vue to the window object?

Comment: I commented this line now, but the bug continues